# Rails how to improve if record exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this model:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events

  def last_event
     events.last
  end
end
```

As you can see, I have a method to get the last event for the device. Now, elsewhere in the Device model I have this method:

```
def place
   self.last_event.place
end
```

Now, if I don't have any records in Events for this Device I get an error "undefined method `place' for nil:NilClass".

And so I added:

```
def place
   self.last_event.place if self.last_event.present?
end
```

And this pattern repeated itself throughout the app, I had to add "if self.last_event.present?" so it won't crash in other places too.

I am sure there must be a better way to handle this kind of thing without the need to check if last_event is present everywhere?

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: I suggest you do the check because whether or not you have to write it. You can use try in Holger's answer but still, you'd better check it explicitly to make sure your app adapt to logic change later. It's my experience.

Answer (score 3):

The `try` method (an addition of ActiveSupport) allows exactly that. If called on a `nil` object, it will just return `nil` too. Thus, both of the following lines are equivalent:

```
self.last_event.try(:place)
# equivalent to
self.last_event.place if self.last_event
```

Comment: So there is now way to check at the last_event method instead of all over the app?

Comment: Not really. About the only way would be to return a [null object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) instead of `nil` like Joe proposed. This however has the downside that it can be hard to distinguish an actual data object from your null object which can lead to strange results if forgotten. *I personally* generally prefer to deal with `nil`s explicitly to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to have the method return a blank object which would respond to calls:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events

   def last_event
      events.last || Event.new
   end

   def place
      self.last_event.place
   end
end

2.0.0p247 :001 > d = Device.new
 => #<Device id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
2.0.0p247 :002 > d.place
 => nil
2.0.0p247 :003 > d.last_event
 => #<Event id: nil, device_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, place: nil>
```

The idea is that if a method always returns an object of the expected type, you never have to worry about subsequent calls encountering a nil object. Of course, this could have other implications - such as the need to determine if you have a valid object or a new one, but this can be checked later with:

```
2.0.0p247 :005 > d.last_event.new_record?
 => true
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can use delegates

```
delegate :last, to: events, allow_nil: true,  prefix: :event
delegate :place, to: event_last, allow_nil: true
```